# Test date value in django views

Tags: django

In order to make sure my database values don't create null value exceptions I created a dummy date of 01-01-0001 in Postgresql.

However I want my views to return none if it's the dummy date in the view.

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
{% if myDate == "0001-01-01" %} 
     None
{% else %} 
     {{ myDate }} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what you get by `myDate`?

Comment: myDate is a date object passed by views.py.

Comment: So, you compare with a string with date objects. You need to compare myDate with a date object not a string

Comment: so do I need to pass in another date object equal to 0001-01-01? or can I create one inside views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django date filter template tag

```
{% if myDate|date:"Y-m-d" == "0001-01-01" %} 
     None
{% else %} 
     {{ myDate }} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: had to change the date to 1-01-01 and then it worked!